# How to create a sequence of numbers in R from min to max with zero as the midpoint?

Tags: r

If I had the following variable.

```
set.seed(20)
variable <- sample(-74:124.2, size = 38)
```

How can I create a sequence of 5 numbers using the min and max values of `variable` and zero as the midpoint (3rd value)?

`seq()` takes the start and end values, but is there a way to do this by specifying a middle value?

```
seq(min(variable), max(variable), length.out = 5)
```

Comment: What would the output look like for this specific case?

Comment: The sequence of 5 numbers is not sampled from `variable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace the `median` of the generated sequence with a specified value:

```
seq(min(variable), max(variable), length.out = 5) -> x        
x[which(x == median(x))] <- 0

#-73.00 -25.75   0.00  68.75 116.00
```

This would work if the `length(x)` is odd.

Comment: Try the method with `variable <- -20:100`. There I get `-20 10 0 70 100`.

Answer (score 2):

You can combine two `seq`.

```
c(seq(min(variable), 0, length.out=3), 
  seq(0, max(variable), length.out=3)[-1])
#[1] -73.0 -36.5   0.0  58.0 116.0
```

This will only work as expected when `min(variable) <= 0` and `max(variable) >= 0`.